# Get DateTime from MySql with php and insert into Chart.js

Tags: php, database, chart.js

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izkpr.png)
What's up guys, I'm working with Chart.js, I'm getting the database info and printing it into my chart, so I can get my chart to be complete, I need to print the DateTime from MySql into the same data from that day. But for some reason, I can get the DateTime from MySql. The date inset as 'dias' it has the type as timestamp and standard as current_timestamp.

I have already tried this:

```php
$day = $row['dias'];
```

This is my PHP code:

```php
 <?php 
      $id = $_SESSION['userId']; 
      $dBname = "infosensor";
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBname);

      $sql = "SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, dias FROM `$id`;";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if ($resultCheck > 0)
      {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          //Valores da corrente
          $valor1 = $valor1 .'"'.$row['sensor1']. '",';
          $valor2 = $valor2 .'"'.$row['sensor2']. '",';
          $valor3 = $valor3 .'"'.$row['sensor3']. '",';
          $valortot = $valortot .'"'.($row['sensor1'] + $row['sensor2'] + $row['sensor3']). '",';
          //Valores da potencia
          $pot1 = $pot1 .'"'.($row['sensor1'] * 127). '",';
          $pot2 = $pot2 .'"'.($row['sensor2'] * 127). '",';
          $pot3 = $pot3 .'"'.($row['sensor3'] * 127). '",';
          $pottot = $pottot .'"'.(($row['sensor1']*127) + ($row['sensor2']*127) + ($row['sensor3']*127)). '",';
          //Puxar o dia e hora da data enviada
          $day = $day .'"'.$row['dias']. '",';

        }
      }
      //Valores corrente
      $datacor1 = trim($valor1, ",");
      $datacor2 = trim($valor2, ",");
      $datacor3 = trim($valor3, ",");
      $datatotcor = trim($valortot, ",");
      $dias = trim($day, ",");
      //Valores potencia
      $datapot1 = trim($pot1, ",");
      $datapot2 = trim($pot2, ",");
      $datapot3 = trim($pot3, ",");
      $datapottot = trim($pottot, ",");
      //Datevalue
      $day = trim($day , ",");
    ?>
```

This is one part of my chart:

```js
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'line', 
        data: {
          labels: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Corrente01",
              data: [<?php echo $datacor1.$day; ?>],
              borderWidht: 5,
              borderColor: 'red',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the result of a `var_dump($row['dias']);` in your while loop? Does it contain the date and time as you expect?

Comment: It's not giving me any info, I actually want to get the date from MySql database

Comment: @Dave So I can print it with my sensors

Comment: If the column name is `dias` it should be in the `$row` variable. Try a `var_dump($row);` at the top of your while loop and see what it contains.

Comment: Hmm, How can I get to print it? Console log?

Comment: I'm going to add the database photo so you can see

Comment: var_dump will print the contents of $row.

Comment: Didn't get anything from it.. :(

Comment: Sounds like you're not hitting your while loop at all then. var_dump `$resultCheck` and see if it contains what you think it should.

Comment: the loop is working cause I can print the other Infos, what's not working is getting the date-time from mysql

Comment: The result is greater than 0

Comment: Not sure what else I can suggest. If `var_dump($row);` right after `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {` doesn't output anything then you should **not** be getting any of the sensor values either. Your select statement looks correct and the name of the column with the date and time matches your select too.

Comment: For some reason, I don't get any data from DateTime, just don't know why, The other sensors data are being printed

Comment: What's your dB Table name aren't you supposed to be querying like this `SELECT ...dias FROM tablename WHERE id='$id'`

Comment: Nop, the table name is the same as the id from the session, I made It like that cause I needed, The id inside the table is auto increment than...

Comment: It actually just worked..

Comment: I just need to know how to get the month now